# Dynamic code Generation at compile time using c#

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-4.0

I need to generate code dynamically while building a c# project[compile time] without using T4 templates. I went through the questions already in stack overflow and all of them use T4 template. Is there a way to do it without using T4 templates? Please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is because that's what T4 templates are for.  You should [edit] and ask a question about what's going on that you can't use T4.

Comment: You can use `CodeDOM` or `Expression`.

Comment: [CodeDOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6.aspx) worked great for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a EXE for code generation using Code Dom and included it in VS Projects using the 
 . In the targets file i referred my exe and when i compile my second project the .cs file gets generated automatically while building the project.